# Contradiction in Gemara over olive oil

Tags: talmud-gemara, tractate-brachot

The Gemara in Berachot 35b discusses why wine merits a special separate beracha. They suggest maybe because it changes forms for the better (grapes become wine), but then reject this by saying olives change form for the better too by becoming olive oil yet they don’t merit a special beracha.

Then on the next amud, 36a, the Gemara tries to compare wheat flour and olive oil. They say that since we say העץ on olive oil even though its form changed, so too we should say האדמה on wheat flour despite its form changing. But then the Gemara rejects this by saying that wheat flour changes form for the better (by becoming bread) but olives don’t change their form for the better.

This clearly sounds like a contradiction over whether olives do or don’t change form for the better. Do any Rishonim talk about this?

Comment: The Gemara on 36b doesn’t mean it that way. It is referring to ANOTHER change for the better that still hasn’t happened by flour, namely, it still needs to become bread. Whereas olive oil is a finished product. Therefore there’s a difference between the change to olive oil vs flour.

Comment: Perhaps the Sefaria explanation does a better job than me in explaining it. https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.36a.7?lang=bi

Comment: @Chatzkel Ah so in other words, by olives there’s two stages, olives and olive oil. But by flour there’s three stages, wheat flour and then bread. So olive oil is already final but the flour could still become bread

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @Chatzkel that clears it up, thank you! The Gemara was just so confusing to me because it used the exact same language as on the previous daf